# Xml with spaces as InnerText

Tags: c#, xml, whitespace

I'm parsing Xml data which has entries like this:

```
<item name="UserText" type_name="gh_string" type_code="10">      </item>
```

I'm supposed to read the 6 spaces as a String, but both the InnerText and InnerXml values of the System.Xml.XmlNode are zero length Strings.

Is there any way I can get at this whitespace data in existing files and what do I need to do in the future to prevent this sort of screw up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML is ignoring that whitespace. If you need to preserve it, you should insert an `xml:space="preserve"` attribute into your elements. Something like this, which I think is going to preserve your whitespace wherever the XML is consumed.

```
<item xml:space="preserve" name="UserText" type_name="gh_string" type_code="10">      </item>
```

Another option that will work with LINQ-to-XML is to use the PreserveWhitespace load option. Example:

```
XElement element = XElement.Parse(xml, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
```

You should also be able wrap the whitespace in a CData tag, haven't tested.

Answer (score 4):

If you are reading in the xml with an XMLReader just use the XMLReaderSettings with IgnoreWhitespace set to false

```
XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create("file",new XmlReaderSettings{ IgnoreWhitespace=false;})
```

Comment: Nope, I use System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml()

Answer (score 3):

If you use `XMLDocument`, set `XMLDocument.PreserveWhitespace = true` before calling `Load`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace.aspx

This works for me fine.