# Read and Insert Space from Xml Node

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I need to get space from a node any Idea?

I have tried these Nodes

```
   <Node>   </Node> 
   <Node>"  "</Node>  
   <Node>'  '</Node>
```

But I am not getting space .

Comment: show your current code and tell us what did you get and what do you expect.

Comment: Use `PreserveWhitespace` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783693/xml-with-spaces-as-innertext

Answer (score -1):

Here are a couple of other options you can try

```
<Node><![CDATA[ ]]></Node>
<Node>&nbsp;</Node>
```

Comment: The CDATA would certainly load a space, but the &nbsp; isn't really equivalent.  Among other things, it requires that particular character entity to be defined; by default, only &lt;, &gt; and &amp; can be counted on.

Answer (score -1):

Without code, we can only speculate as to what you're attempting to do and why it isn't working.  That being said, white space is not significant in an XML document.  These three Node elements are all treated identically

```
<doc>
    <Node></Node>
    <Node> </Node>
    <Node />
</doc>
```

**Possibly** what you want to do is load your XML with whitespace preserved. For example:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument()
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
doc.LoadXml( "Some file path goes here" );
```

Comment: Kinda curious why a year later this answer was downvoted.  Is there some part of it that was incorrect?