# WordProcessingDocument not preserving whitespace

Tags: excel, xml, linq, ms-word, whitespace

I'm writing a C# program using XML and Linq that reads in data from tables stored in a word document and inserts it into an excel spreadsheet. The code I have so far does this, however it does not preserve any new lines (in the word doc the "new line" is done by pressing the enter key). Using the debugger, I can see that the new lines aren't even being read in. For example, if the text I want to copy is:

```
Something like this
And another line
And maybe even a third line
```

It gets read in as:

```
Something like thisAnd another lineAnd maybe even a third line
```

I can't separate the lines by a character as the words could be anything. This is what I have so far:

```cs
internal override Dictionary<string, string> GetContent()
    {
      Dictionary<string, string> contents = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(MainForm.WordFileDialog.FileName, false))
      {
        List<Table> tables = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Table>().ToList();
        foreach (Table table in tables)
        {
          TableRow headerRow = table.Elements<TableRow>().ElementAt(0);
          TableCell tableSectionTitle;
          try
          {
            tableSectionTitle = headerRow.Elements<TableCell>().ElementAt(0);
          }
          catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
          {
            continue;
          }
            List<TableRow> rows = table.Descendants<TableRow>().ToList();
            foreach (TableRow row in rows)
            {
              TableCell headerCell = row.Elements<TableCell>().ElementAt(0);
              if (headerCell.InnerText.ToLower().Contains("first item"))
              {
                contents.Add("first item", row.Elements<TableCell>().ElementAt(1).InnerText);
              }
              else if (headerCell.InnerText.ToLower().Contains("second item:"))
              {
                char[] split = { ':' };
                Int32 count = 2;
                string str = row.Elements<TableCell>().ElementAt(0).InnerText;
                String[] newStr = str.Split(split, count, StringSplitOptions.None);
                contents.Add("second item:", newStr[1]);
              }
**continues for many more else if statements**
              else
              {
                continue;
              }
            }
        }
        return contents;
      }
    }
```

I'm new to using XML, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I believe XML by default ignores leading and trailing whitespace in elements. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783693/xml-with-spaces-as-innertext) has some options for overriding that, but it depends on having access either to the original XML or the ability to set parsing options at the time the XML is read. Not sure if this is useful in your case.

Comment: Newlines make no sense in *any* word processing application, because the actual line breaks are calculated by the application itself when displaying or printing a document. When you hit Enter you create a new paragraph. When you hit Shift-Enter you create a soft line break.

Comment: `InnerText` is the text content of an element stripped of any other tags. By using `InnerText` you're explicitly asking for text without line breaks and paragraphs. You should inspect the cell contents instead and retrieve the contents of any paragraphs nodes or line breaks